# How do I migrate from a JBOD configuration to a single-volume setup?

Tags: cassandra

Need some help with something I couldn't find a solution online. I have CassandraDB running on a server. This server has 3 mounted volumes /data1, /data2 and /data3. In my scylla.yaml file, I've specified the working_directory and data_file_directories to all of these three mounted volumes so data is being written to all three of them. I want to get rid of all of these three volumes (500GB each) and store all my data in a single 2TB volume. How do I go about this?

I thought of taking a snapshot and restoring it all in the new 2TB volume, but when I take a snapshot it stores in /volume/keyspace/table-uuid/snapshots/snapshot_name. The table names are all same in all three volumes (with different uuid ofcourse) but the data/SSTables in each of these volumes is different although the table name is same.

If anyone could point out what's going wrong or lead me to a resource that could resolve my issue, I'd be very grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How many nodes are in the cluster?

Comment: It is a single node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are multiple nodes in the cluster, the easiest answer here is:

- Decommission the node.
- Rebuild the hardware/instance with the desired disk configuration.
- Rejoin the node to the cluster.
- Repeat for each node as required.

Comment: Hi Aaron,

Thank you for your reply. The instructions you've mentioned here are suitable for expanding a mounted volume maybe but my issue is different. Basically, I have 3 mounted volumes. Let's call it sda, sdb and sdc. In cassandra.yaml, the path to store data is datadrive1 mounted on sda, datadrive2 mounted on sdb and datadrive3 mounted on sdc.

The keyspace kairosdb is on all of these three drives and the names of these .db files is also the same but the content inside all of these are different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple procedure you can try on a non-production cluster:

1. Flush all data in memtables to disk with `nodetool drain`.
2. Shutdown Cassandra on the node.
3. For each table, move the SSTables from the 3 subdirectories to the new corresponding subdirectory on the 2TB volume.
4. Update `cassandra.yaml` to remove references of the old volumes and replace them with the single mountpoint for the new 2TB volume.
5. Start Cassandra.

Finally, verify that your application can read the data. Cheers!